# Startup problem with Ubuntu 10.10 on VirtualBox on Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I've been running Ubuntu 10.10 on VirtualBox on Windows. Today I got the following error message:

```
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.


BusyBox v1.15.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.15.3-1ubuntu5) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: This isn't a programming problem.  Try Super User.

Answer (score 2):

People  [here](http://wwww.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1167710)  seemed to have fixed it with a file system check.
so it might be a corrupted file system.

Have you tried to boot a live system image (you can directly mount the iso from Virtualbox) and check the filesystem of the virtual hard drive?

Comment: Phi, I copied the .iso file that I was using. In VirtualBox, I created a new "Ubuntu" from the copy, and I am installing it now.

Comment: In your link, someone said that using a recovery mode in GRUB should fix the issue. I did so, but I still got the black screen with white text. What commands will check the filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I could resolve the issue by following the below steps:

```
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg
```

The solution in the end was to use GParted.

1. Download and put GParted onto a thumb drive and boot
2. Get GParted to check your filesystem
3. Reboot

Bingo, rebooted and everything was completely back to normal.

I got this information from here: http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=80959